Find if any row parameter value was equal to 1 in period of time
I have a problem constructing a query.
I had table like this:



Id
Start Date
Parameter Value




1
NULL
1


2
2023-10-01 00:00:00.0000000
0


3
2024-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
0



I need to find out if any row valid between 2023-01-01 and 2024-12-31 contains a parameter value equal to 1. In this case, the script should return true, because the first parameter whose start date is null is valid until 2023-09-30, i.e. it was valid in the first half of 2023. Do you know how to do it right?

"because the first parameter whose start date is null is valid until 2023-09-30" why is it valid till then? What date is it valid from? There's nothing to denote it's valid on that date in your data. It's NULL, it's an unknown value.

You haven't showed us the query you are having trouble with...

Use ISNULL(LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Start Date]) OVER(ORDER BY ID), '20991231') to get the next date as enddate and then you should be able to figure the rest out, trust me

If that is the right path, @siggemannen . I hope that don't have NULL values between dates. :)

Why you don't store the start- and end-date in one row, that would make it much easier. I also don't understand why you have another row with value 0 with a new start-date. In seems to be redundant because the 0-period hasn't ended yet.

@ThomA "why is it valid till then? What date is it valid from? " It is valid from the beginning until any other row exists. Only the first row can have a start date of null. I don't like the way it was solved but I have to extract such information from the existing database.

So NULL actuallu represents something like 1900-01-01, 0001-01-01 or some other arbitrary date before 2023-10-01?

@ThomA Yes, something like 0001-01-01

@siggemannen Thank you! That way solve the problem :) I used ISNULL(LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Start Date])) OVER(ORDER BY [Start Date]), '20991231') with WHERE condition and its works fine.

As mentioned in the comments, you can use LEAD (or LAG) to get the value for the next row. I assign a arbitrary values for the first row's start date and the last row's end day ((0001-01-01 and (SYSDATETIME() respectively) to remove the NULL values. Then we can check if there is a row in the range. Depending on where this is, you might then also have AND C.ParameterValue = 1 and the query is in an EXISTS, but I've used conditional aggregation here to return a pseudo-boolean depending on if there is a relevant row or not:
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Id,
           ISNULL(V.StartDate,'0001-01-01') AS StartDate,
           LEAD(V.StartDate,1,SYSDATETIME()) OVER (ORDER BY V.StartDate) AS EndDate, --SYSDATETIME() ebcause I wanted an endvalue
           V.ParameterValue
    FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(datetime2(7),NULL),1),
                (2,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2023-10-01 00:00:00.0000000'),0),
                (3,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2024-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'),0))V(Id,StartDate,ParameterValue))
SELECT MAX(CASE C.ParameterValue WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InRange
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.EndDate >= '20230101'
  AND C.StartDate < '20250101';

